# GroupBy in Deedle

Tags: deedle

I want to group my dataframe by certain columns and then iterate over the groups like I can easily do using the LINQ .GroupBy().

```
var groupedByTags = dataFrame.GroupRowsUsing((i, series) => GetTags(series));
// GetTags extracts my groupKey
```

does do the grouping, but I couldn't figure out how to iterate over the groups. I think the GetByLevel function might help, but it seems I need to know the groups first before I can use it.

Also I'm using the C# version of deedle.